# Empty data on List in LinQ Statement

Tags: c#, linq, list

I got this LinQ statement

```
var daysList = new List<int>(new int[30]);

 var model_pdv = db_pdv.Pdv.GroupBy(x => new { Pdv = x.Clave_PDV, Nombre_Pdv = x.Nombre_Pdv})
            .Select(x => new DishVM()
            {
                Clave_PDV = x.Key.Pdv,
                Nombre_Pdv = x.Key.Nombre_Pdv,
                Days = daysList,
                Data = x
            }).ToList();
```

However i dont know why my "Data" List inside my LinQ gets empty values the first time but then i saves the LinQ as it should

This is my DishVm Class:

```
 public class DishVM
{
    public string Clave_PDV { get; set; }
    public string Nombre_Pdv { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Pdv> Data { get; set; }
}
```

And my Pdv class:

```
 public class Pdv
{
    public string Clave_PDV { get; set; }
    public string Nombre_Pdv { get; set; }
}
```

How can i avoid the empty Data List?

Comment: `daysList` is instantiated as an empty List no wonder it is empty

Comment: daylist is not the one empty, its "Data=x" wich gives me the first value empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `x` within your `Select` statement is IGrouping, change it to produce a list:

```
var model_pdv = db_pdv.Pdv.GroupBy(x => new { Pdv = x.Clave_PDV, Nombre_Pdv = x.Nombre_Pdv})
            .Select(x => new DishVM()
            {
                Clave_PDV = x.Key.Pdv,
                Nombre_Pdv = x.Key.Nombre_Pdv,
                Days = daysList,
                Data = x.ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @benPearce
this was the whole problem and adding a .ToList() to my Data solved thank you =)